# Using PGPASSWORD variable does not seem to work any more on Postgresql 9.3

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

In Posgresql you can set a variable called `PGPASSWORD` (and `PGUSER`) so you don't have to use password when using postgresql commands such as `psql` or `pg_dump`

But I am a bit confused because I can't get it to work on Postgresql 9.3.10 and it's still documented on their site as if it should work.

so commands like

`PGPASSWORD=password psql -l`

will not work.

Neither can I declare them before hand such as

`PGUSER=root`

`PGPASSWORD=password`

`psql -l`

It still asks for password (although in this case, it uses the root user as it should)

The only way I have got it to work somehow was by doing the `.pgpass` file but it only works when using a specific database, asterisk doesn't work and it only works with pg_dump, not all postgresql commands like `psql -l`:

`localhost:5432:*:root:password`

These are my `pg_hba.conf` settings if it helps any:

```
local   all             root                                md5

    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   all             all                                     peer
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: PGPASSWORD works the same with all versions. Besides, It's not a feature of the server, it's interpreted by libpq, the client library. Anyway please share the error/output messages instead of "it doesn't work".

Comment: There is no error message, it just asks for the password as it normally would or just plain says that the users is not recognized, even when I specified root in another variable.

Comment: you're typing `export ` first right?

Comment: I confirm this environment variable no longer functions with the `psql` version bundled with Postgres 9.3. A few scripts I had recurring to this mechanism stopped working. Apparently, `psql` simply ignores the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the way to make it work with all databases and commands is by adding the following in the .pgpass file:

`localhost:5432:dbname:user:password
localhost:5432:*:user:password`

If you add only the second line it won't work, you need to add both.

Bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative for those who do not want .pgpass file and want to execute in a single command line instance.

```
set "PGPASSWORD=yourpass" && createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres new_db_name
```

I referred almost every solution related to command line and finally ended by wrapping `"` around PGPASSWORD=yourpass while setting in Windows 11.